# Access Dynamics 365 database from third party application

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm trying to access the SQL Server database behind our Dynamics 365 installation. There's a nice step-by-step guide how to do that here:

https://dynamics-chronicles.com/article/how-access-dynamics-365-online-sql-server-database

I followed all steps and can easily connect from SQL Server Management Studio. Very, very cool!
However when I try to use a third party app to go the same way to access the server, I get the attached error message, saying the this app must be preauthenticated somewhere. But I don't understand how to do that and what that means?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY13E.png]

Can someone point me in the right directions?
It looks like the app is submitting some kind of identifier that must be white listed somewhere?!

Answer (score 0):

I get this error too with the OleDb provider.

```
PS C:\Users\david> $con.open()
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Failed to authenticate the user 'dbrowne@microsoft.com' in Active
Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive').
Error code 0xCAA20002; state 10
AADSTS65002: Consent between first party application 'db465503-d247-463e-8a13-95889346b742' and first party resource
'00000007-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' must be configured via preauthorization - applications owned and operated by
Microsoft must get approval from the API owner before requesting tokens for that API.
Trace ID: fc6fc7d2-1c95-431f-861e-db45297c3500
Correlation ID: 0b0fb2f8-248f-489a-9ed1-a4584b9d8d12
```

ODBC works, though (I had to use ActiveDirectoryInteractive because MFA is required in my tenant).

```
PS C:\Users\David> $con2 = new-object system.data.odbc.odbcconnection
PS C:\Users\David> $con2.connectionstring="driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};server=xxxx.crm.dynamics.com;authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;UID=xxx@yyy.com"
PS C:\Users\David> $con2.Open()
```

If you have to use OleDb you can use [MSDASQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-odbc?view=sql-server-ver16), the OleDb provider for ODBC to use this ODBC driver from an OleDb client.